# LINQ join error in Release mode

Tags: c#, linq, join

I use Sql Server compact database, and my linq query work properly in debug mode, but it has error in release mode !
My query use "join" and the exception is:

> The method ' 
>   [My_Project_Namespace.MyTransactions,My_Project_Namespace.Users].
>   ' is not a property accessor

Here is my LINQ query:

```
var result = from transRow in db.MyTransactions
             join userRow in db.Users on transRow.User_id equals userRow.Id
             join clientRow in db.Clients on 
                transRow.Client_id equals clientRow.Id
             select new
             {
                 userId = transRow.User_id,
                 clientId = transRow.Client_id,
                 userName = userRow.Fname + " " + userRow.Lname,
                 clientName = clientRow.Fname + " " + clientRow.Lname,
                 reg_date = transRow.Reg_date,
                 value = transRow.Value
             };
```

My aim is add (or replace) the user id with his name and also the client id with his name.

Comment: Are you sure your project is building correctly? Everything ticked in the Build -> Configuration Manager?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043821/performance-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that's because of using some obfuscators like "Eazfuscator.NET".
but it will work with some other obfuscators like "Babel" !

Answer (score 2):

as **Oleksiy Gapotchenko** (Eazfuscator.NET Developer) said [here](http://groups.google.com/group/eazfuscator-net/browse_thread/thread/41e0d4741e86d87a?pli=1)
you need to add this on the assembly level:

```
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "anonymous type properties renaming", Exclude = true)]
```

then, all of your anonymous method and types won't be obfuscated, and (probably) will work....