# @ServiceHost Debug="true" - performance penalty?

Tags: .net, wcf, performance, svc

Is there a performance penalty of setting Debug="true" in the svc file? Is it significant enough to warrant setting it to "false" in a production environment?

```
%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" **Debug="true"** Service="AwesomeService" %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `".svc"` file, if you are writing your service as **inline** code, or implementing service in "**App_Code**" folder and enabling `debug` mode, it will impact the performance.

Generally, always set `debug="false"` before you deploy to production. If debug mode is enabled, the performance of your application can be decreased.

> In Release mode, the debug symbols are not baked into the assembly, so
>   you cannot debug it using Visual Studio .NET or other source code
>   debuggers. What's cool is that the code is also optimized during this
>   build operation.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that this switch controls debug symbols generation only for inline code.

Debug symbols for code-behind generation controlled by other options.

If you have no inline code, you don't hit the performance.

---

Meanwhile [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967286.aspx) the following:

> Debug
>
> Indicates whether the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) service should be compiled with debug symbols. true if the WCF service should be compiled with debug symbols; otherwise, false.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **yes** but if you want all the gory details, look at this good [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043821/performance-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds?answertab=votes#tab-top) on the topic.

Comment: This blog entry is pretty old and somewhere out-of-date.

Comment: Old does not imply incorrect, the effect of debug = true is still applicable in IIS 7.5 and there are internal compiler optimization that are turned off when an assembly is complied with debug = true regardless of which version of ASP.NET you use. If you have any specifics on inaccuracies please explain.