# Release vs Debug Build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have a .net 4.0 class lib project and when I compile it in release I noticed the binary (.dll) is not smaller in size than the debug.  Why is this?  Shouldn't it be smaller?  It should also execute a bit faster no?  Also, how can I tell if a .dll has been built as debug or release?

Comment: This depends on the size of the build. If you have a large build, requiring many symbols to be saved for debugging, the release might be significantly smaller.

Comment: @bash.d: debug is 98K and release is 97K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *very* little difference in the IL that the C# compiler generates when you build the Release version of your assembly.  The only notable thing it does is omit the NOP instructions that help you set a breakpoint on a curly brace.  Just a few tidbits beyond that like not emitting an empty class constructor.  All small stuff, only related to making it easier to debug code.  Given the default `/filealign` option, odds are good that the resulting assembly is not smaller.  Or is just a few kilobytes less.

The C# compiler doesn't have a built-in optimizer, that's not its job.  The optimizer is built into the jitter.  Controlled by an attribute that the compiler emits, [DebuggableAttribute.IsJITOptimizerEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggableattribute.isjitoptimizerdisabled.aspx) property.  Which is *true* for the Debug build and *false* for the Release build.  You can see its value with ildasm.exe

You'll find the kind of optimizations performed by the jitter described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043821/performance-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds/4045073#4045073).

Answer (score 1):

Debug and Release executables (dll's, exe, whatever) are identical unless you use #if DEBUG compiler directives in your code. 
Difference is that a debug compile generates .pdb files containing debugging info.

This tool can help you to find out if the dll is debug or release: http://assemblyinformation.codeplex.com