# How do I add different profiles to an asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have an asp.net project on VS2012 with one profile only "Debug".
I keep changing manually the web.config and I would like to use Transformation instead but I understood that different profiles are needed to make transformations.
How do I add new profiles in the solution, debug, testing, production to be able to use transformations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the menu bar: Build -> Configuration Manager and select New in the "Active solution configuration" drop down.

There are more than configuration transformation to the build configuration - see this answer for more info: [Performance difference between debug and release builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043821/performance-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds/4045073#4045073)