# Release Build for using FluentValidation get error

Tags: c#, build, fluentvalidation

I build my project as Debug mode that FluentValidation is a part of my library NO PROBLEM

When I build my project in debug mode all things is successful 
BUT when I use release mode FluentValidation Not found !!!

but when changed it to Release mode FluentValidation Not found !!! AbstractValidator not found and I get error !

```
The type or namespace name 'FluentValidation' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'AbstractValidator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I dont need to know Release Vs Debug mode in General , I need to know Why FluentValidation dont Build in release mode (I want to publish my WCF Host and I have problem)

**WHY ??**

**What is different between Release and Debug mode for using FluentValidation library ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason you need to change from DeBug to Release mode and then re-install Fluent via the Package Manager Console i.e. `PM> install-package FluentValidation`

This worked for me anyway.

Answer (score -1):

This should help you out .

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326647/FluentValidation-and-Unity
2. [Performance differences between debug and release builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043821/performance-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds)
3. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shivprasadk/difference-between-debug-vs-release-mode/

Comment: I dont need to know Release Vs Debug mode in General , I need to know Why FluentValidation dont Build in release mode ???