# Including debug files on Production Website

Tags: asp.net, debugging

If this is a duplicate question, I apologize in advance. I am sure someone has asked it before, but I didn't find it. Anyway, here it goes.

I have a complicated web application that is in production. From time to time, we get errors that are logged, including the stack trace, but are difficult to pin down. I would like to have access to the line numbers of the error, which requires the debug files be present on the server.

I see a lot of advice always about not including those files for security reasons. I am less concerned about that in this instance. Is there any other downside to including the debug files on the production site, such as a dip in performance?

Edit: 
Just to refine the question a bit, I am proposing to still compile the application to Release mode, but to also include the PDB files in the solution.

Comment: There will likely be a performance hit.  See this detailed answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043821/performance-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what your uptime requirements are, one option would be to deploy both the Release and Debug folders side by side and switch between them. Basically you have your `bin` folder as per normal and you can have a `bin_debug` directory next to it.

During normal production, you just run from bin directory as usual. If you want to track down a bug or an error, rename `bin` to `bin_release` and `bin_debug` to `bin`. You will have a performance hit for a few days while you track down the bug, but you will get more detailed error messages. Once you've identified the issue, you can switch back to the release directory.