# Is some reflection code optimized at compile time?

Tags: c#, optimization, reflection, compile-time

I think some code using reflection can be optimized (I'm not sure we can call it optimize) at compile time.

- For example, `System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod` always returns the same value when it is called in the same method.
- Also, accessing a class info using class name represented constant string has no reason to be done at run time.

I have tested it and I got a result that shows a code with reflection is about 300x slower than one without reflection.

Are there any compile option(s) that enable what I want?

Comment: Take a look in [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163759.aspx) regarding reflection performance.

Comment: What you're asking about sounds similar to *caller information attributes* (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540(v=vs.110).aspx). Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be an equivalent for current method info, so your best bet will be simply caching the `GetCurrentMethod` return value.

Comment: I can't think of a specific case for example 1 but for the second the information certainly can change (if you update the DLL hosting the class for example)

Comment: You completely overlook [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4045073/17034).  The inlining optimization makes GetCurrentMethod() return something else.  The only point of using a string is that you *don't* know what class it might be.  The compiler of course doesn't either.  Sure, replacing code that takes a nanosecond, like a method call, with Reflection is inevitably going to be a lot slower.

Answer (score 2):

For the case of `System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod`. This is usually used for getting the name of the current method call.

If this is the use case

```
public void Foo()
{
    var method = System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
    Log.Log(string.Format("I is inside of {0}", method.Name));
}
```

Then you should replace this with

```
public static MemberName([CallerMemberName] memberName = null)
{
    return memberName;
}

public void Foo()
{
    Log.Log(string.Format("I is inside of {0}", MemberName()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reflection in .net is indeed painfully slow. There is nothing much one can do about this.

On the other hand, it may be suitable for you to use 'fasterflect' `http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/`, which implements several features of the built-in .net reflection with improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

All reflection can be cached and execute once. I recommand it to preserve performance and extensibility. (valuate static fields for exemple in static constructor)

Method like getcurrent...thing is a lazy shortcup code. You know where you are... You can keep yours methodinfo in static private field to use them.