# Class Variable UnChanged by Asyncronous Method

Tags: c#

**EDIT:** I know this is bad code, that's why I tagged it with `anti-pattern`.

OK, so this is some actual real code I found today:

```
public class ServiceWrapper
{
    bool thingIsDone = false; //class variable.
    //a bunch of other state variables

    public string InvokeSoap(methodArgs args)
    {
        //blah blah blah
        soapClient client = new Client();
        client.doThingCompleted += new doThingEventHandler(MycompletionMethod);
        client.doThingAsync(args);

        do
        {
            string busyWork = "";
        }
        while (thingIsDone == false)

        //do some more stuff
    }

    private void MyCompletionMethod(object sender, completedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do some other stuff
        thingIsDone = true;
    }
}
```

OK, so I'm aware of why this is bad, obviously. But what's actually making me ask this question is, `thingIsDone` never seems to be `true` in the `InvokeSoap` method, even if set true in `MyCompletionMethod`, but *only if complied in Release*. It behaves as one would "expect" in Debug mode.

Adding `Thread.Sleep(100)` inside the `while` loop also fixes it. What's up with this?

Comment: 1) _Please_, **never ever do that**.  2) You need `volatile`.

Comment: Also, you have a `thingIsDone` and a `thisIsDone` - is that intentional?

Comment: This code won't compile -- there are typos and syntax errors. Can you provide an actual example?

Comment: Cleaned up the code, thanks.

Comment: Second bullet in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4045073/17034).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CPU may cache the value of `thingIsDone`, since that thread cannot change it between reads.

You need `volatile` to force the writes to be published so the other thread can read it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.Yield()` in the loop.

```
do
{
    string busyWork = "";
    Thread.Yield();
}
while (thingIsDone == false)
```