# Is it a good idea to create Release configuration with Full debug information?

Tags: c#, .net

I am about to ship a first release of my software to a client and want to be able debug it, if something goes wrong.
It is a good idea to generate full debug information for a release configuration ? Will it run slower if the debug info wasn't generated ? Should I give debug files to my client ? 
Running it in .NET 4.5.1

Comment: `want to be able debug it, if something goes wrong`. How are you going to do that exactly if the code is running on your "client's" machine?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange from what I have read, .NET can generate memory dump that I can use, though I might be wrong.

Comment: it is not good idea. it run slower.

Comment: @newprint see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043821/performance-differences-between-debug-and-release-builds)

Comment: @hasanaydogar Unless you have something to back that up, I would strongly disagree, the PDB files do not impact performance. If you expect to have to debug the application after it is released, by all means include the debug information, otherwise you'll find it very difficult to work through problems.

Comment: Consider IntelliTrace with http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/08/07/intellitrace-standalone-collector-is-back.aspx IntelliTrace Collector on client machine instead.

Comment: It does not run slower unless you start the program with the debugger attached.  You'd normally use the debugger's Attach command so the process isn't affected at all.  Be sure to practice debugging a release built program, you're bound to be dismayed with the experience if you never done that before.