# Does the .NET Roslyn compiler produce better optimised IDL

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I understand that the Rosyln .NET compiler exposes a new API for interacting with the compiler, but does it also produce better optimised IDL that will ultimately be more performant than the previous compiler?

Comment: IDL as in "interface definition language" for COM interfaces?

Comment: Clearly he did not mean IDL.  Probably IL.  And yes, they did optimize a bit more than the old compiler.  Just a bit, mostly visible due to the bugs that caused, particularly so in VB.NET.  It is not the job of the C# compiler or Roslyn to optimize, it is the [jitter's job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4045073/17034).