# How does the "ThrowHelper" .Net Framework class help lessen the generated IL code?

Tags: c#, except, intermediate-language

I was looking at [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/throwhelper.cs,73669ffe9b1ee4f4) and it its starting comments it says it exists because

```
throw new ArgumentNullException("key", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_Key"));
```

generates more IL code than

```
ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key, ExceptionResource.ArgumentNull_Key);
```

which I can't find in the code, but like its similar methods I assume just calls `throw new ArgumentNullException("key", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_Key"));` or something.

Does the ThrowHelper class really help lessen the IL code generated or is it the same (or more) considering the IL code generated from `ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key, ExceptionResource.ArgumentNull_Key);`?

EDIT:
The IL shown at the start of the file, in the comments, is only from the call to `ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key, ExceptionResource.ArgumentNull_Key);` not the actual code inside that method. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It literally shows you the IL at the top of that file...

Comment: @IanKemp, it shows the IL generated from the `ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key, ExceptionResource.ArgumentNull_Key);` it does not show the IL generated from the `ThrowArgumentNullException`'s inner workings.

Comment: The IL from the "inner workings" is irrelevant since it only occurs once. Of course the *total* size of IL is larger if you only call `ThrowArgumentNullException` once, but the trick is that it's called many times.

Comment: And in particular, reducing the IL size in many methods can be important for inlining.

Comment: Nothing to do with the IL, it is used to let the jitter generate better machine code.  Methods that contain `throw` cannot be inlined.  Inlining is one of the basic [machine code optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4045073/17034), the method entirely disappears and the code is generated inside the calling method.  By using ThrowHelper that problem is solved, exceptions don't need to be fast.  It is a micro-optimization, which are evil but the kind of thing you have to do when you create a framework and cannot guess where your methods are being used.