# Getting the compiled asm of a c# program

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, assembly, jit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve JIT output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928442/retrieve-jit-output)

Is this possible to do, and if so how (I would need to be after its JITed i think, but I have no idea how to go about doing this)?

Comment: Assuming it were possible, *which* compiled ASM would you want? The JIT'ed ASM could be situation-dependant.

Comment: do you want the MSIL?for this you have ILDasm

Comment: @Arafangion I am not so worried about that, I'll take any asm that is generated. Yosy, I want what is going to the processor, not the MSIL or the CIL code.

Comment: @JonAlb: processor can't execute IL, it executes asm commands. And you can see them from native debugger like WinDbg. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928442/retrieve-jit-output/

Comment: Can I get the asm as it is complied?

Comment: @soandos: yes, but with some efforts.

Comment: So this is a duplicate. Thank you @Ivan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view the jitted assembly with the Visual Studio Debugger (*Debug* -> *Windows* -> *Disassembly*).

If you start the program with the debugger already attached (*F5* in Visual Studio) then you'll see the non-optimised version of the assembly that's generated when the jitter detects such a situation.

If you need the optimised, non-debug version of the jitted assembly then you'll need to compile your program in Release mode and start it without the debugger attached (*Ctrl+F5* in Visual Studio). Then attach the debugger to the running process once you know that the required section of code has already been jitted. Then you can break and view the jitted assembly.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm always assuming that one wants to see asm to analyze _actual_ and _precise_ code behaviour. VS is not a good thing for such investigation. But in general it is enough to grasp what's going on in principle. +1

Answer (score 3):

.NET uses a just-in-time compiler.  The machine code isn't generated until the last possible moment, just before a method starts executing.  That makes it pretty difficult to 'capture the ASM'.

If you are just interested in what it looks like then right-click the source code window while debugging and select "Goto Disassembly".  You are not looking at the 'real' machine code until you debug the Release build and re-enable the JIT compiler optimizer with Tools + Options, Debugger, General.

Another option is to run ngen.exe, the 'pre-compiler' for .NET.  A foo.dll assembly will produce a foo.ni.dll assembly in the c:\windows\assembly or c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly directory.  This .ni.dll image file contains the jitted machine code.