# Why is using structure Vector3I instead of three ints much slower in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, x86, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization

I'm processing lots of data in a 3D grid so I wanted to implement a simple iterator instead of three nested loops. However, I encountered a performance problem: first, I implemented a simple loop using only int x, y and z variables. Then I implemented a Vector3I structure and used that - and the calculation time doubled. Now I'm struggling with the question - why is that? What did I do wrong?

**Example for reproduction:**

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public struct Vector2I
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Z;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public Vector2I(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }
}

public class IterationTests
{
    private readonly int _countX;
    private readonly int _countY;
    private readonly int _countZ;
    private Vector2I _Vector = new Vector2I(0, 0, 0);


    public IterationTests()
    {
        _countX = 64;
        _countY = 64;
        _countZ = 64;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void NestedLoops()
    {
        int countX = _countX;
        int countY = _countY;
        int countZ = _countZ;

        int result = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < countX; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < countY; ++y)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < countZ; ++z)
                {
                    result += ((x ^ y) ^ (~z));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void IteratedVariables()
    {
        int countX = _countX;
        int countY = _countY;
        int countZ = _countZ;

        int result = 0;

        int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            result += ((x ^ y) ^ (~z));

            ++z;
            if (z >= countZ)
            {
                z = 0;
                ++y;

                if (y >= countY)
                {
                    y = 0;
                    ++x;

                    if (x >= countX)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void IteratedVector()
    {
        int countX = _countX;
        int countY = _countY;
        int countZ = _countZ;

        int result = 0;

        Vector2I iter = new Vector2I(0, 0, 0);
        while (true)
        {
            result += ((iter.X ^ iter.Y) ^ (~iter.Z));

            ++iter.Z;
            if (iter.Z >= countZ)
            {
                iter.Z = 0;
                ++iter.Y;

                if (iter.Y >= countY)
                {
                    iter.Y = 0;
                    ++iter.X;

                    if (iter.X >= countX)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void IteratedVectorAvoidNew()
    {
        int countX = _countX;
        int countY = _countY;
        int countZ = _countZ;

        int result = 0;

        Vector2I iter = _Vector;

        iter.X = 0;
        iter.Y = 0;
        iter.Z = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            result += ((iter.X ^ iter.Y) ^ (~iter.Z));

            ++iter.Z;
            if (iter.Z >= countZ)
            {
                iter.Z = 0;
                ++iter.Y;

                if (iter.Y >= countY)
                {
                    iter.Y = 0;
                    ++iter.X;

                    if (iter.X >= countX)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<IterationTests>();
    }
}
```

**What I measured:**

```
                 Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
----------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
            NestedLoops | 333.9 us | 4.6837 us | 4.3811 us |
      IteratedVariables | 291.0 us | 0.8792 us | 0.6864 us |
         IteratedVector | 702.1 us | 4.8590 us | 4.3073 us |
 IteratedVectorAvoidNew | 725.8 us | 6.4850 us | 6.0661 us |
```

Note: the 'IteratedVectorAvoidNew' is there due to discussion that the problem might lie in the `new` operator of Vector3I - originally, I used a custom iteration loop and measured with a stopwatch.

Additionally, a benchmark of when I iterate over a 256×256×256 area:

```
                 Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
----------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
            NestedLoops | 18.67 ms | 0.0504 ms | 0.0446 ms |
      IteratedVariables | 18.80 ms | 0.2006 ms | 0.1877 ms |
         IteratedVector | 43.66 ms | 0.4525 ms | 0.4232 ms |
 IteratedVectorAvoidNew | 43.36 ms | 0.5316 ms | 0.4973 ms |
```

**My environment:**

- Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40GHz
- Windows 10, 64 bit
- Visual Studio 2017
- Language: C#
- Yes, I selected Release configuration

**Notes:**

My current task is to rewrite existing code to a) support more features, b) be faster. Also I'm working on lots of data - this is the current bottleneck of the whole application so no, it's not a premature optimization.

Rewriting nested loops into one - I'm not trying to optimize there. I just need to write such iterations many times, so simply wanted to simplify the code, nothing more. But because it's a performance-critical part of the code, I'm measuring such changes in design. Now, when I see that simply by storing three variables into a struct I double the processing time... I'm quite scared of using structs like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relates to the difference between a memory access and a register access.

**TL;DR:**
With raw variables everything can be placed into registers, whereas with a struct everything has to be accessed from the stack, which is a memory access. Accessing a register is significantly faster than accessing memory.

Now, onto the full explanation:

C# is JIT compiled at launch (this is slightly different from the JVM, but that isn't important right now), because of this we can see the actual assembly generated (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410181/how-to-see-jit-compilated-code-in-net-vm-clr) for how to view it).

For this I am only comparing `IteratedVariables` and `IteratedVector` because you're going to get the general gist with just these. First we have `IteratedVariables`:

```
                    ; int countX = 64;
in   al, dx  
push edi  
push esi  
push ebx  
                    ; int result = 0;
xor ebx, ebx  
                    ; int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
xor edi, edi  
                    ; int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
xor ecx, ecx  
xor esi, esi  
                    ; while(true) {
                    ;     result += ((x ^ y) ^ (~z));
LOOP:
    mov eax, edi  
    xor eax, ecx  
    mov edx, esi  
    not edx   
    xor eax, edx  
    add ebx, eax 
                    ; ++z;
    inc esi  
                    ; if(z >= countZ)
    cmp esi, 40h  
    jl  LOOP  
                    ; {
                    ;     z = 0;
    xor esi, esi  
                    ; ++y;
    inc ecx  
                    ; if(y >= countY)
    cmp ecx, 40h  
    jl  LOOP  
                    ; {
                    ;     y = 0;
    xor ecx, ecx  
                    ; ++x;
    inc edi  
                    ; if(x >= countX)
    cmp edi, 40h  
    jl  LOOP  
                    ; {
                    ;     break;
                    ; } } } }
                    ; return result;
mov eax, ebx  
pop ebx  
pop esi  
pop edi  
pop ebp  
ret
```

I've done a little work to clean up the code, all of the comments (lines marked with  semicolons (`;`)) are from the actual C# code (these were generated for me), I've cleaned them up a bit for brevity. The primary thing you should notice here is that everything is accessing a register, there is no raw memory access (A raw memory access can be somewhat identified by `[]` around a register name).

In the second example (`IteratedVector`) we will see a slightly different code piece:

```
                                    ; int countX = 64;
push ebp  
mov  ebp, esp  
sub  esp, 0Ch  
xor  eax, eax  
mov  dword ptr [ebp-0Ch], eax  
mov  dword ptr [ebp-8],   eax  
mov  dword ptr [ebp-4],   eax  
                                    ; int result = 0;
xor ecx,ecx  
                                    ; Vector3i iter = new Vector3i(0, 0, 0);
mov dword ptr [ebp-0Ch], ecx  
mov dword ptr [ebp-8],   ecx  
mov dword ptr [ebp-4],   ecx  
                                    ; while(true) {
                                    ;     result += ((iter.X ^ iter.Y) ^ (~iter.Z));
LOOP:
    mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-0Ch]  
    xor eax, dword ptr [ebp-8]  
    mov edx, dword ptr [ebp-4]  
    not edx  
    xor eax, edx  
    add ecx, eax  
                                    ; ++iter.Z;
    lea eax, [ebp-4]  
    inc dword ptr [eax]  
                                    ; if(iter.Z >= countZ)
    cmp dword ptr [ebp-4], 40h  
    jl  LOOP  
                                    ; {
                                    ;     iter.Z = 0;
    xor edx, edx  
    mov dword ptr [ebp-4], edx  
                                    ; ++iter.Y;
    lea eax, [ebp-8]  
    inc dword ptr [eax]  
                                    ; if(iter.Y >= countY)
    cmp dword ptr [ebp-8], 40h  
    jl  LOOP  
                                    ; {
                                    ;     iter.Y = 0;
    xor edx, edx  
    mov dword ptr [ebp-8], edx  
                                    ; ++iter.X;
    lea eax, [ebp-0Ch]  
    inc dword ptr [eax]  
                                    ; if(iter.X >= countX)
    cmp dword ptr [ebp-0Ch], 40h  
    jl  LOOP  
                                    ; {
                                    ;     break;
                                    ; } } } }
                                    ; return result;
mov eax, ecx  
mov esp, ebp  
                                    ;  {
                                    ;      break;
                                    ;  } } } }
                                    ;  return result;
pop ebp  
ret
```

Here you will distinctly notice lot's of raw memory accesses, they are identified by the square brackets (`[]`), they also have the tag `dword ptr`, don't worry too much about what that means, but just think of it as `Memory Access`. You will notice that the code here is riddled with them. They are everywhere that a value access from the struct occurs.

This is the reason why the struct code is so much slower, registers are right next to the CPU (literally inside it), but memory is far away, even if it is in the CPU cache it will still be significantly slower to access then registers.

Comment: It's exceedingly unlikely that `in   al, dx` actually executes as part of this function.  It will fault in user-space.  Probably you started disassembling from the middle of an instruction.  But anyway, good answer.  Store/reload latency is about 5 cycles, so keeping a loop counter in memory is a big bottleneck for a small loop.  Silly compiler.

Comment: Formatting tip:  you should indent the comments a lot farther to the right, so you can visually scan down the column where asm instructions start without them distracting your eye.  Putting comments on the same line as an instruction works well.

Comment: @PeterCordes Now that you mention it that `in` instruction is a bit odd. It was in the dissassembler output, everything else looked fine. who knows.

Comment: @PeterCordes I shifted the comments over a bit, I was kind of expecting it to format the code as NASM and not whatever C based language it chose, if it had chosen NASM it would be a lot easier to read.

Comment: @vandench Now I will scream in horror for several hours... anyway, thanks for the detailed explanation, I really appreciate it, it completely change my perspective on writing (performant) code in C#. They said the compiler is smart to inline things like that, they said the compiler is smarter than me.

I think this should be taught with the C# language; until now I thought the main performance penalty comes from all classes being allocated on heap, null and array bounds checks and perhaps from little too much of virtual calls, but this is on completely different level...

Comment: @Tom C++ compilers are probably able to make better optimizations but C# usually has some limitations on what it is allowed to do, it also probably makes debugging easier. Anyways, glad I could help.

Comment: @vandench Yeah, now I'm selecting which parts of code should I rewrite to C++. About making debugging easier: AFAIK that's why debug builds doesn't inline at all.